# How to publish two apps under one IIS Website

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an Angular2 App, and a Web api.

I currently have one IIS website to publish the each the Angular2 App and Web api.

How can I publish those two apps under one IIS Website?

Answer (score 1):

You can publish any number of web application under one iis server, you may need 1 port to publish angular app and 1 port for webapi.

check the below link for your reference
[here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/hosting-asp-net-web-api-rest-service-on-iis-10/)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by :
Add publish in the root of the website under iis
and add the other application as a web application under the website itself